# Unable to connect to mongo on remote server

Tags: 14.04, server, iptables, firewall, mongodb

I have installed mongo on machine1(`Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server`) in my local network. I have also opened the port `27017` as mentioned in [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#traffic-to-and-from-mongod-instances) guide using following commands:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Current rules are (`iptables -L`):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
```

---

But I am not able to connect to this port from machine2 (in the same network):

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.0.108
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 192.168.0.108:27017/test
2016-01-23T18:02:14.848+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 192.168.0.108:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-01-23T18:02:14.850+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.0.108:27017 (192.168.0.108), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

I also tried checking if port is opened or not:

```
$ nc -v 192.168.0.108 27017
nc: connectx to 192.168.0.108 port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Must be some silly mistake as I am setting up mongo for the first time. Pls help.

**Some more info**

1. Mongo daemon is running. I am able to connect to mongo form the same machine but not from the other machine. The daemon is running:

   ```
   $ service mongod status
   mongod start/running, process 31205
   ```

   and the port is 27017

   ```
   $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 27017
   tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:27017 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 31205/mongod
   ```
2. I changed the `bind_ip` to `0.0.0.0` (as suggested somewhere) and restarted mongo. Still the same error is coming.
3. Distro Info:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/*release
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
   NAME="Ubuntu"
   VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
   ID=ubuntu
   ID_LIKE=debian
   PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
   VERSION_ID="14.04"
   ```

Comment: Did you confirm that the bind_ip actually changed to 0.0.0.0 by re-running the netstat command?

Comment: Yes you are right. `bind_ip` didn't change because of some issue in restarting mongo. Pls answer so that I can accept Or I will answer with your solution.

Comment: Please go ahead and add your own answer - I know nothing about mongo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was `bindIp` didn't change. There was some issue in restarting mongo from my side.

The habit should be to verify if the bindIp actually changed or not. (using `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 27017`)

Thanks steeldriver for pointing it out.